# change value in dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, return-value, onchange

In the code below, I changed the value and it changed in the same block, but when the loop repeats again, the changes are not applied at the beginning of the loop.

```
while True:    
    airplane_ticket = {'Berlin':'','price':'$700', 'available':5}   
    print(airplane_ticket)  
    name_ticket = input('please enter the name of city you want to reserved its ticket: ')  
    if name_ticket == 'Berlin':
        number = int(input('How many ticket you need: '))    
        airplane_ticket['available'] -= number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value of `airplane_ticket` to be `{'Berlin':'','price':'$700', 'available':5}` at the start of every loop, so no matter what you set it to afterwards it will always be overwritten.

Bringing the initialisation statement for `airplane_ticket` outside the `while True:` loop should fix this.

```
airplane_ticket = {'Berlin':'','price':'$700', 'available':5}   
while True:
    print(airplane_ticket)  
    name_ticket = input('please enter the name of city you want to reserved its ticket: ')  
    if name_ticket == 'Berlin':
        number = int(input('How many ticket you need: '))    
        airplane_ticket['available'] -= number
```